# Trouble importing function from one views.py to another app in django

Tags: django

I have two apps **login** and **someother**

I am trying to import a function like

```
From login.views import save
```

In `someother.views.py`

But getting `ImportError: No module named views`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

Here it is.

My app name was "login" and have feature.py in the same.

when i tried to import feature using

from login import feature

IDE was not showing any issues. intellisense was working fine.

but when i tried to runserver it thrown ImportError: No module named feature. 
and as soon as i changed login to extended_login it worked.

So i think some Keywords are not acceptable as app names or there is already a (system) app named with that keywords which actually do not have a module you trying to import.